# callback successfull camera can not called ? what is the reason for ?

Tags: angularjs

I can not catch the callback from this method, I spend alot of time to find reason.
 what is reason ? if we separate the callback out of the function so that same the result.
could help me find the solution ?

```
//angularjs controller
function CtrlSubmit ($scope) {
// body...
$scope.linked="...";
$scope.type="N/A";
var options = { limit: 1 }
$scope.clickCapture = function() {
    navigator.device.capture.captureImage(
    function(imgcontent) {
     // console.log(imgcontent[0]);
      $scope.$apply(function(){
         $scope.linked=imgcontent[0].fullPath;
 });
 },
function(err) {
   $scope.linked = "err";
 },
 {limit:1});
};

}

//view 
<div ng-controller='CtrlSubmit' >
<button ng-click="clickCapture()">Take Picture</button>
{{linked}}

</div>
```

Comment: Does it catch the error callback?

Comment: You are aware that `navigator.device.capture.captureImage` is something from the PhaneGap API, aren't you? Did you test it on a device which is able to processor this (i.e. a supported platform)?

Comment: @ dirkk: I use cordova.js, dont use the phonegap.js, in phonegap use the getPicture(). How do I can fix it ?
@BenDiamant: yes can not step into callback method, I dont know why ?

Comment: nobody can help me about this ?